# How to color merge commit when use pretty format?

Tags: git, git-log

I have already the pretty format log oneline like this

```
g help ll
'll' is aliased to 'log --oneline --first-parent --pretty='%C(yellow)%h %C(cyan)%ai %Cblue%an%C(auto)%d %Creset%s''
```

I want to print more pretty to color the merge commit msg specially.  How can I get to it ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean that you want to color a merge commit message *differently* from an ordinary (non-merge) or root commit message: you can't do that with `%`-directives in Git as there's no option for testing the number of parents.

Comment: Is it possible  we check the "Merge"  key word to acheive that ?  @torek

Comment: Not with `%`-escapes. There are no general conditionals in `%`-escapes. The `Merge: ...` text is also not available from a %-escape; it's hardcoded into some of the formats. Git's escapes are easier to use than Mercurial's but are less powerful.